# A question in $I$-adic rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

An $I$-adic noetherian ring is a noetherian ring which is separated and complete in the I-adic topology for some ideal $I ⊂ A$.

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two prime ideals of $A$ which contain $I$, and let $n,m$ be two positive integers such that $n<m$. Fixed an element $x_1\in p_1$, if there exists some element $x_2\in p_2$ such that $x_1-x_2\in I^n$, does there exist an element $x_3$ in $p_2$ such that $x_1-x_3\in I^m$ ？

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where does this question come from? What have you tried?

Comment: @k.stm I just want to prove that there is a natural bijective between $spec A/I^m$ and $spec A/I^n$. When I wanted to prove that the natural map is well-defined and injective, I encountered this question...

Comment: Let $A$ be a commutative ring. For every prime $\mathfrak p ⊆ A$ and every ideal $I ⊆ A$, you already have
$$\mathfrak p ⊇ I^n \iff \mathfrak p ⊇ I.$$
This already implies that $\operatorname{Spec} A/I^n \cong \operatorname{Spec} A/I \cong \operatorname{Spec} A/I^m$. No further assumptions are needed.

Comment: I know the facts what you said and I know there is a 1-1 corrspodence between $spce A/I^n$ and {prime ideals in $A$ which contain $I^n$}. But I still want to know the answer to the question I raised at the beginning... Thanks all the same.